# Sharing data in distributed system environment

Tags: events, microservices, distributed-system

I have a question regarding sharing data in distributed system environemnt.
Usually I am using scenario A, ie. I am pushing messages from system A to a remote Queue such as Amazon SNS/SQS and I am expecting system B to pick the message up when system B is up and running.

I have thought about it and I came with an alternative that I am not sure is good enough. Basically, System A now pushes message to local queue and local queue pushes message to system A. Prerequisites for this are that both systems A and B are up and running and that queue is specific only for system A, ie. there is no system C, D, E... that are pushing  message to the same (duplicate) local queue somewhere on C, D, E.

Is this a good alternative?

I was also considering scenario B as a backup plan for scenario A, when remote queue is unavailable and I dont want to lose a message. In that case system B would be a remote queue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the scenario C is actually the way distributed messaging should be and is actually done  . This is called **outbox** pattern in Async communication. There kind of patterns are used for resiliently publishing to the event bus . Its very much like mail box where your mail box keeps your email in the outbox until delivered. The bit of a tweak is that instead of local queue use persistent storage.

But you need to have worker which will be looking for pending messages and will publish them as soon as queue is available.

You can find more about this pattern here.

[Outbox pattern](http://gistlabs.com/2014/05/the-outbox/)

[Resiliently publishing to the event bus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/asynchronous-message-based-communication#resiliently-publishing-to-the-event-bus)

Comment: When you say scenario B, you are actually referring to scenario C?

Comment: @mko , My bad yes it's scenario C. I have updated my answer.

Comment: In order to avoid message loss with local messaging solutions, is it recommended to use DB or file for message persistance?

Comment: DB is preferred practice since it also becomes your log .  In fact the top practice is to save the data in local database and pick the message from transaction log and publish it.

Comment: That was my thinking, but on the other hand DB could be unavailable , but file system is always up and running.

Comment: You can make it as resilient as you like. File system is definitely not the preferred approach.  To handle the case where your DB is not available you can save it in cache. You may need to provision distributed cache in this case. Your worker will look for cache if DB is not available and save them in DB later when available. Really up to you how you want to design .